# Google tag manager redirects to another page product

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, drupal, drupal-7, google-tag-manager

I've spent last five days looking for solution for google tag manager and nothing find.
I've instal GTM module for the Drupal 7 and got next generate code and behaving for page of product.

I noticed strange behaviour in GTM after enabling GTM in google admin page.
He automatic redirect to another page product after i clicked in on product.
I have understand way why this happens with img 1 but don't now how to fix it.

[differents urls in datalayer and current location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znW1u.png)

Comment: I found old plugin in legacy code, where were duplicated functions GTM and worked not correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. That you are redirected is the expected behaviour.

There is an [eventCallback](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/hitcallback-eventcallback/) in the dataLayer. There specified is a JS function that is executed when the tags associated with that event have been fired. In your case that JS function is a redirect, and it redirects to "https://constructors.com.ua/lego-super-heroes/lego-super-heroes-perehvat-kriptonita-76045", so if that is what you are seeing then everything works as it should.